# python MYSQL, check for a condition OR no records then insert new record

Tags: python, mysql-python

can the below if - else stament be simplifed into a single if (cond1 OR cond2) statement

condition 1 would be `state`== specific value (either a 1 or a 0) and condition 2 would be no records found

```
sql1 = "SELECT state FROM YO WHERE function = '%s' ORDER  BY time DESC LIMIT 1" %(func)

if (not(myresult2)): #No records, do the insert
    print ("doing insert %s - %s - %s" %(func,newstate,time))
    cursor.execute(sql2)
else:
    #check state . if matches do nothing
    if (myresult2[0][0] != newstate):
        print ("doing insert %s - %s - %s" %(func,newstate,time))
        cursor.execute(sql2)
db.commit()
```

Comment: You should fix your code. Formatting, indentation, `sql1` → `sql2`, `commit` on a `SELECT` only (or something missing?)...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use string formatting to substitute variables, use parametrized statements. See [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)

When you fetch the result, check whether it's empty or the value is not `newstate`

```
sql1 = "SELECT state FROM YO WHERE function = %s ORDER  BY time DESC LIMIT 1" cursor.execute(sql1, (func,))
row = cursor.fetchone()
if not row or row[0] != newstate:
    print ("doing insert %s - %s - %s" %(func,newstate,time))
    cursor.execute(sql2)
```

It's may also be possible to do this as a single SQL query, but it won't be as clear as this.